# integer values for onbindviewholder recycler view

Tags: java, android

I just want to show my int values of this (price), how to write code that int values can be shown. For your information on my model name is a string and price is an integer

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) 

{
   myViewHolder.name.setText(milk.get(i).getname_milk());
   myViewHolder.price.setText(milk.get(i).getprice());
}
```

Comment: @Ashish string values show, but integer not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Easy way

```
myViewHolder.price.setText(milk.get(i).getprice()+"")
```

Answer (score 0):

**`textView.setText()` support only string as parameter.**

Write like this

```
myViewHolder.price.setText(String.valueOf(milk.get(i).getprice()));
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
myViewHolder.price.setText(milk.get(i).getprice().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
myViewHolder.price.setText(String.valueOf(milk.get(i).getprice()));
```